# цикл не завершается в коде - С++

Tags: c++

есть проблема, не могу завершить цикл не смотря то что там есть break; помогите пожалуйста[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
//not - !
//and -&&
// or -||
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, g;
    unsigned rand_value = 11; //а это до скольки работает рандом ну там от 0 до 11
    srand(rand_value); // рандомизация генератора случайных чисел
    c = 1 + rand() % 10;// рандом чисел
    d = 1 + rand() % 11;// рандом чисел
    g = 1 + rand() % 6;// рандом чисел
    a = 800;
    cout << "you have " << a << " dollars" << endl;
    cout << "enter 1 if you are want to play a game" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    while(true)
    {
        if ( b == 1)
        {
            a -= 100;
            while (a > 100)
            {
                cout << " start the game" << endl;
                cout << "|| " << c << " || " << d << " || " << g << " ||" << endl;
                if (c == d == g)
                {
                    cout << " yes!" << endl;
                    a += 300;
                    break;
                }
                else if (c == d != g || c == g != d || g == d != c)
                {
                    cout << " so - so" << endl;
                    a += 150;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << " No" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                // этот кусок кода отвечает за выигрыш и проигрыш
                if (a >= 1500)
                {
                    cout << " you win!";
                    break;
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (a < 100)
                {
                    cout << " game over";
                    break;
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " good buy" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Варианты выхода из глубоко вложенного цикла в порядке от плохого к хорошему - использовать исключение, использовать переменную-флаг, указывающую, что нужно выйти из всех циклов (или определенного их количества), немного изменить логику. В вашем варианте я бы рекомендовал последнее. Одно то, что в каждом ветвлении вы ставите `break`, уже наводит на грустные мысли...

Answer (score 2):

break выходит только из одного цикла, внешний цикл будет работать бесконечно.

Answer (score 0):

Как указал LlShy2, у вас отсутствует `break` во внешнем цикле. Таким образом у вас получается:

```
while(true)
{
    if ( b == 1)
    {
        a -= 100;
        while (a > 100)
        {
         // ....
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " good buy" << endl;
        // ---> Наверное, здесь нужен break <----
    }
}
```

Получается бесконечный внешний цикл. Но беда еще в том, что присваивание переменной `b` у вас происходит до цикла. И поэтому в цикле она у вас постоянно равна 1. Вам необходимо переделать  программу так, чтобы ввод был в цикле:

```
while(true){
    cout << "Введите 1 для продолжения";
    cin >> b;
    if (b == 1) { 
        // ваш код 
    }
    else { 
        // ваш код good bye...
        break;
    }
```